# Pre-built AMQP and STOMP client (as in GUI client)

Tags: activemq-classic, rabbitmq, amqp, stomp

I'm looking for a client (as in GUI client, not client library) to play with our MQ server and familiarize myself with its semantics. Something that will send and receive messages at the press of a button (or a text command) and maybe even update me about the status of the server queues and messages. Administration would be a bonus. The UI doesn't have to be graphical (i.e. command line clients are fine).

The server will probably run RabbitMQ so anything RabbitMQ-specific is fine, as is ActiveMQ. But I'd rather have a generic AMQP or STOMP tool.

So, does anything of the sort exist?

I know some management and monitoring tools come with both server distributions, but no clients, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [BQL](http://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-bql.html) RabbitMQ plugin.

It gives you an SQL-style language for AMQP.  For instance,

```
BQL> create exchange myexchange;
ok
BQL> create durable queue 'myqueue'
ok
BQL> select name,messages from queues where 'durable'=true order by name
----------------------
| name    | messages |
----------------------
| myqueue | 0        |
```

Obviously, it's RabbitMQ specific.

If you're willing to do a bit of coding, you could take a look at the examples in the RabbitMQ Java and .NET clients:

- [Java examples](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-java-client/file/dd9e10fb5771/test/src/com/rabbitmq/examples/)
- [.NET examples](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/file/e43fa199ed82/projects/examples/client/)

They're not quite graphical, but trying to understand them forces you to ask the right questions.

It's been a while, but I remember thinking that the best way to familiarize yourself with AMQP is to read the [0-9-1 spec](http://www.amqp.org/confluence/display/AMQP/AMQP+Specification-) and write some simple programs; in particular, the protocol documentation on that site gives a lot of examples.

Comment: Well, there's also the Stomp plugin, but I can't comment on it.
https://dev.rabbitmq.com/wiki/StompGateway

Comment: Also, if you have any questions (anything AMQP-related really), drop a line on the RabbitMQ-discuss mailing list.
http://lists.rabbitmq.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/rabbitmq-discuss

Comment: I was afraid of this. Not too bad, though: I started writing Java again after some 5 years and I got to learn some Ant as well. I'll indeed be writing my own AMQP client using Rabbit's Java library but in the meanwhile I'll play around with BQL. Thanks.

Comment: BQL turned out to be the tool I was looking for. Thanks! (I've also printed out the protocol specification)

Answer (score 7):

For Apache ActiveMQ, there is

- the web admin console at http://localhost:8161/admin/
- the [ApacheActiveMQBrowser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/activemqbrowser/) project on Sourceforge:

> An open source project of developing
>   Message admin gui based tools for
>   Apache ActiveMQ.

- [HermesJMS](http://www.hermesjms.com/), it does not mention ActiveMQ 5 (only 3 and 4) on the [plugin page](http://www.hermesjms.com/confluence/display/HJMS/ActiveMQ), but there is an active [user forum](http://hermesjms.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=5)

Comment: Though I've decided on using RabbitMQ, I'll still play around with ActiveMQ using two of the tools you mentioned (I already know about the web interface.) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `rabbitmq-management` plugin that comes with RabbitMQ (and enabled by `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`) has a web-based interface that listens on the port 15672 and can do everything you are (I was) asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Command line tools (written in C) to send and receive AMQP messages: http://github.com/rmt/amqptools